# XQuery-Update: Target node of insert expression is not updateable

Tags: xquery, saxon, basex, xquery-update

Running this code

```
copy $foo := <foo />
modify (
  insert node <bar /> into $foo
)
return $foo
```

in Saxon-EE 9.6.0.7 (form Oxygen 18) I get the Error

> Target node of insert expression is not updateable

BaseX returns `<foo><bar/></foo>`

Who is right? Is there another way to modify any xml-expression, not just those loaded by doc() (which works with Saxon)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the option `-tree:linked` to ensure that Saxon runs using an updatable tree model. The default tree model is immutable.

Comment: thanks its working now. btw oxygen provides a checkbox "use linked tree model" here: Preferences / XML / XSLT-FO-XQuery / XQuery / Saxon-HE/PE/EE